# Creating a 2-D array of integer triplets in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I am trying to create a 2-D array of integer triplets R, G and B using the following code:

```
 BitmapColours [,] PrevImage = new BitmapColours [1, 1];

    public class BitmapColours
    {
        public  int R { get; set; }
        public  int B { get; set; }
        public  int G { get; set; }

    }
```

but when I try to set a triplet value using

```
PrevImage[0,0].R = -1;
```

I get the error "Object Reference not set to an instance of the Object"

Comment: c# as in the title

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting happens because you're trying to access a field `R` using a null reference. (See [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for the C# error, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_pointer for information about `null` in general).

According to the official Microsoft C# guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/), the following occurs when an array is first created:

> The default values of numeric array elements are set to zero, and reference elements are set to null

Your type `BitmapColours` is defined as a class, which is a reference type (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/classes), so every entry in your array is initialized to `null`. You need to first create an instance of your class for that index, and then your code will work. It should look something like this:

```
BitmapColours [,] PrevImage = new BitmapColours [1, 1];
PrevImage[0,0] = new BitmapColors();
PrevImage[0,0].R = -1;
```